# DirectX swapchain flicker C++

Tags: directx

I'm using DirectX to allow a user to 'color'/draw in a Win8 app.  Much of the drawing code is similar to the Ink Drawing sample that MS has out.

Apologies for the length. I'm struggling to describe the problem briefly.

I'm having issues where, when the user draws a new line in live drawing mode with an InkStroke, that new line is invisible *except* for a segment being added (while the mouse is moving each finishing segment flashes and then disappears).  When I release the mouse it joins my collection of Strokes which render as normal. That is, once you're done drawing a line what you tried drawing looks fine/visible/like you drew it.

I had this working fine as a stand alone C++ desktop app.  However, I then connected the SwapChainPanel to an XAML page which also has a Menu. That was when the issue arose. They use the XAML menu to choose an image to color in and the page switches to 'drawing mode' with the desktop app code. The same SwapChainPanel handles context switching on the XAML page and with the drawing buffers.
I believe the problem lies in that the XAML page is using the same SwapChainPanel as the drawing buffers. This is interfering with a call "m_d3dContext->CopyResource(_currentBuffer.Get(), _previousBuffer.Get());"  which is how the rest of older part of the 'currently being drawn' line is captured for drawing.

How can I get around this?  Is there a solution which would not involve separating it into 2 XAML pages (one for menu, one for drawing), each with their own SwapChainPanel? Even if that is the best way, is there a way to do it with one XAML page?

Comment: ,Eworfle You use Windows 8.1, don't you?

Comment: I don't think anyone has done the upgrade on my machine to 8.1 yet, unless the wife did it sneakly and I didn't know.  I should still be in pre-8.1, but I'll check when I get home and update this.  
I've seen some notes about DirectX changes with 8.1. Did I miss something relelvant?

Comment: I wanted to be sure you were using Windows 8.1 Preview because you use the SwapChainPanel component (introduced in this new version).